# Not able to upload files on Virtual Machine

Tags: php, ubuntu, file-upload, virtualbox

I am not able to upload files on Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager 5.2.0.
I am using Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, precisely OSGeoLive11 package and files are being uploaded from Desktop of VM itself. Code works over other live server.

upload.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="../upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
// database configuration on oracle VM
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_PORT', 5432);
define('DB_NAME', 'test');
define('DB_USER', 'test');
define('DB_PASS', 'test');

// connect to a database
$conn = pg_connect("host=" . DB_HOST . " port=" . DB_PORT . " dbname=" . DB_NAME . " user=" . DB_USER . " password=" . DB_PASS);
if (!$conn) {
    $error = error_get_last();
    echo "Conn error: " . $error['message'] . "<br>";
} else {
    echo "Connected! <br>";

    if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
        print_r($_FILES);
    }
}
?>
```

Output on VM:

```
Connected! 
Array ( )
```

What do I need to adjust?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have this issue with all files with different sizes?

Comment: I just tried with what I needed until now: 2 files at once, 58,6 KB and 204 KB, both gpx formats.

Comment: It seems that it works with txt and pdf files, but not with gpx files. How come?

Comment: Well if you didnt ask I would have not thought of it, I wasnt owner of of files! Should have been testing more, but as I am new to VM, I thought it might be smth because of it.

Comment: Well, I'm glad you could find the cause of your error. Today's lesson: check for the file permission - checked ;)

Answer (score 0):

I realized I wasn't owner of any of the files I've been testing on VM. I guess I need to write on my wall sticker - check permissions first!